# Shell script rename and move files from one folder to the other

Tags: bash, file, shell, unix

I am very new to Unix.

I have a folder with files of format

```
ABC-DEF-Somestring.100-03-06-2015
ABC-DEF-Somestring.200-03-06-2015
```

Need to move it to another folder with filenames as

```
ABC-DEF-Somestring.100-04-06-2015
ABC-DEF-Somestring.200-04-06-2015
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command can automate the rename process:

```
rename 's/03-06-2015$/04-06-2015/' *
```

Then use the move command:

```
mv source/files destination/
```

Hope this helps.